Wrong dependency installed with pip
I wonder if anyone could please help me with this issue:
I have two python libraries lime and specsy, where  the first library is a dependency of the second.
At the time when I added lime to PyPi there was another library with the same name so I declared it as lime-stable.
I have now uploaded specsy to its PyPi but when I try to install it this happens:
a) It installs the third party "lime" library (not mine)
b) It installs an older version of specsy.
I have actually declared it as "lime-stable" in three different places:
a) The project.toml which I think is the expected place:
[project]
name = "specsy"
version = "0.2.2"
readme = "README.rst"
description = "Model fitting package for the chemical analysis of astronomical spectra"
dependencies = ["arviz~=0.18",
                "astropy~=6.0",
                "corner~=2.2",
                "h5netcdf~=1.3.0",
                "jax~=0.4",
                "jaxlib==0.4.26",
                "lime-stable~=1.0",
                "lmfit~=1.3",
                "matplotlib~=3.8",
                "numpy~=1.26",
                "pandas~=2.2.2",
                "pymc~=5.13",
                "PyNeb~=1.1",
                "pytensor~=2.20",
                "scipy~=1.13",
                "six~=1.16.0",
                "toml~=0.10",
                "tomli >= 2.0.0 ; python_version < '3.11'",
                "xarray~=2024.3.0"]

b) The requirements.txt file
arviz~=0.18
astropy~=6.0
corner~=2.2
h5netcdf~=1.3.0
jax~=0.4
jaxlib~=0.4
lime-stable~=1.0
lmfit~=1.3
matplotlib~=3.8
numpy~=1.26
pandas~=2.2.2
pymc~=5.13
PyNeb~=1.1
pytensor~=2.20
scipy~=1.13
six~=1.16.0
toml~=0.10
tomli >= 2.0.0 ; python_version < "3.11"
xarray~=2024.3.0

c) and the setup.py file:
  packages=find_packages('src'),
  package_dir={'': 'src'},
  package_data={'': ['config.toml', 'inference/*', 'innate/*', 'models/*', 'operations/*', 'resources/*', 'workflow/*']},
  include_package_data=True,
  install_requires=["arviz", "astropy", "h5netcdf", "jax", "jaxlib", "lime-stable", "lmfit", "matplotlib", "numpy",
                    "pandas", "pymc", "PyNeb", "pytensor", "scipy", "toml", "xarray"],

But it still installs "lime" instead of "lime-stable" from pip.
I wonder if anyone coculd please point me towards the source of the conflict.

Use something like deptree or pipdeptree to figure out what depends on what. This should tell you why lime was installed, maybe something else has a dependency on lime that you did not know about.

Thank you very much @sinoroc. Not sure why but it works now... Do you think I should just keep the dependencies in one place? Which one?

So i tried to pip install specsy. It pulled theright version 0.2.2 as shown in the pip freeze > requirements.txt output
lime-stable==1.0.0
lmfit==1.3.1
logical-unification==0.4.6
markdown-it-py==3.0.0
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
matplotlib==3.8.4
.
.
.
specsy==0.2.2
Sphinx==7.3.7
sphinxcontrib-applehelp==1.0.8
sphinxcontrib-devhelp==1.0.6
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==2.0.5
sphinxcontrib-jsmath==1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp==1.0.7
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==1.1.10
stack-data==0.6.3
tinycss2==1.3.0
toml==0.10.2


So I am not able to recreate the error you are talking about. The versions are also the ones you have in PyPi packages.

Thank you very much @Polarimetric not sure what happened but it works now. Incidentally, do you think I should just keep the requirements on the requirements.txt?

I think it does not hurt to have the requirements.txt file. However going forwardpyproject.toml is the way to go. Check out this question and answers within.
